# JQuery GridView Grouping Summary

Tags: html, asp.net

I need a jquery grid which supports grouping, filtering, inline editing and showing summary on header not on footer.

I tried jqgrid, but as i've seen, it doesn't support Filtering.

Comment: It does support filtering/searching http://www.guriddo.net/demo/mobile/indexdemo.html#searching. and http://www.guriddo.net/demo/mobile/demo/toolbarsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
**https://datatables.net/**
DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library.